# How to preview css color codes in Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: colors, css, dreamweaver

Editing some css code. If I delete the '#' sign the color widget pops up allowing me to select a new color. But I'd like to know how I can see what color 'e9f4fa' is. From within the dreamweaver cs5.

theme_topbar_background_color: #e9f4fa;
  theme_topbar_menu_background_color: #79b4d4;

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Styles panel to preview a color (Window | Styles).  With the Panel open, click on the element in design or code view and all colors declared will show under the "Properties" bar in that Panel.

You can also invoke the color picker by doing Edit | Code Hint Tools | Color Picker